# Sets Not Showing "In" Function Tableau Public

Tags: set, tableau-api

When trying to create a set using tableau public, I create the parameter with no problem but when I try to create the set, not only does it create the set in the dimension category instead of a separate sets category for some reason, it doesn't show an "In" option in the filter, only an "Out". Also yes I know you are supposed to have the set in the "Filters" section, but I was just trying other stuff to see if I could get it to work. [image]

I have tried everything I can think of however I cannot get the "In" option to appear in the sets filter. I have also tried googling my problem and cannot find a single instance of someone experience the same problem that I am now. If anyone could provide some assistance as to why this may be that would be great.

Comment: this is a known issue, a limitation you can say

Comment: @MKD alright as long as it's not something on my end. I'm still just learning and practicing so as long as I at least know how to use sets then that's good enough for me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: if you need any help, feel free to connect me here : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar